# Using globbing pattern with fs.watch('dir', fn)

Tags: javascript, node.js

Attempting to watch for all file changes under `src`, including subdirectories like `src/main/css`, etc. using node's `fs.watch()`.  First I tried `fn.watch('src/**/*.*', ...)` however that throws an error.  Is there a way to get globbing to work with `fs.watch()` or do we need to use something like [chokidar](https://www.npmjs.com/package/chokidar) or [gaze](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gaze)?

Implemented it like this with gaze, but would be nice to just use `fs.watch()`:

```
    gaze('src/**/*.*', (err, watcher) => {

        if (err) {
            console.log(err);
            throw new Error(err);
        }

        /**
         * Triggered both when new files are added and when files are changed.
         */
        watcher.on('changed', function (filepath) {
                   ...

        });
    });
```